# Very basic rails link_to issue

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

Hello all I have a Delete link that I'm trying to create with the following code:

```
 <%= link_to 'Delete', element, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

However the resulting link is /element.id where the id is the integer id. How would I change that . to a / sorry I know this is very elementary but I couldn't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 <%= link_to 'Delete', destroy_modelname_path(element), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Replace `modelname` with the name of your model.

Run `rake routes` in terminal in your app to see all routes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in `config/routes.rb`, it should contain a reference to `element`, like:

```
resources :element
```

Comment: Once I add that in it gives me an error of: "undefined method `element_path'"

Comment: Do you have a controller `ElementsController` (plural!) in file `app/controllers/elements_controller.rb`, containing the method `destroy` (destroy is the corresponding method to HTML's DELETE request)?

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with routes file. It seems that your routing routine writes id in the place of :format.